# AspectJ - pointcut advice based on annotated function

Tags: annotations, aop, aspectj, aspect, pointcut

I have 2 custom annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface FlowPoint {
    public enum PointInFlow {
        START, END
    }
    PointInFlow pointInFlow();
}
```

and:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ScopeAnnotation {
    public enum Category {
        BUSINESS, DETECTION, INTERNAL_FUNC, THRESHOLD
    }
    Category category() default Category.DETECTION;
}
```

At my code I annotated a method with `PointInFlow.START` and some others with `Category.DETECTION` and `Category.BUSINESS`

my pointCuts are:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(flowPoint) && if()")
public static boolean executeStartMethod(<annotationPackage>.FlowPoint flowPoint) {
        return flowPoint.pointInFlow() == FlowPoint.PointInFlow.START;}

@Before("executeStartMethod(flowPoint)")
public void beforeStartMethod(<annotationPackage>.FlowPoint flowPoint, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoBefore(jp, flowPoint.pointInFlow());}

@After("executeStartMethod(flowPoint)")
public void afterStartMethod(<annotationPackage>.annotation.FlowPoint flowPoint, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoAfter(jp);}


@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(scopeAnnotation) && if()")
public static boolean executeDetectionMethod(<annotationPackage>.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation) {
        return scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.DETECTION;}

@Before("executeDetectionMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void beforeDetectionMethod(<annotationPackage>.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoBefore(jp, scopeAnnotation.category());}

@After("executeDetectionMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void afterDetectionMethod(<annotationPackage>.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoAfter(jp);}


@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(scopeAnnotation) && if()")
public static boolean executeBusinessMethod(<annotationPackage>.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation) {
        return scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.BUSINESS;}

@Before("executeBusinessMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void beforeBusinessMethod(<annotationPackage>.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoBefore(jp, scopeAnnotation.category());}

@After("executeBusinessMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void afterBusinessMethod(<annotationPackage>.annotation.ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.infoAfter(jp);}
```

The issue is DETECTION and BUSINESS separately are working, (when I comment out one of the detection or business pointcut definition.) but not as above together.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the following AspectJ compile error:

```
circular advice precedence:
  can't determine precedence between two or more pieces of advice that apply to the same join point:
  method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doEight())
```

As a work-around you can do this:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(scopeAnnotation) && if()")
public static boolean executeDetectionOrBusinessMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation) {
  return
    scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.DETECTION ||
    scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.BUSINESS;
}

@Before("executeDetectionOrBusinessMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void beforeDetectionOrBusinessMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
  infoBefore(jp, scopeAnnotation.category());
}

@After("executeDetectionOrBusinessMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public void afterDetectionOrBusinessMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, JoinPoint jp) {
  infoAfter(jp);
}
```

Or if you insist in separating the pointcuts and advices for both annotation values, just use around advices instead of before/after:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(scopeAnnotation) && if()")
public static boolean executeDetectionMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation) {
  return scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.DETECTION;
}

@Around("executeDetectionMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public Object aroundDetectionMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
  infoBefore(jp, scopeAnnotation.category());
  try {
    return jp.proceed();
  } finally {
    infoAfter(jp);
  }
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(scopeAnnotation) && if()")
public static boolean executeBusinessMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation) {
  return scopeAnnotation.category() == ScopeAnnotation.Category.BUSINESS;
}

@Around("executeBusinessMethod(scopeAnnotation)")
public Object aroundBusinessMethod(ScopeAnnotation scopeAnnotation, ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
  infoBefore(jp, scopeAnnotation.category());
  try {
    return jp.proceed();
  } finally {
    infoAfter(jp);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment I used these ways and I got the below error and it doesn't so much clear what's the problem, I tried search on google and I found it could be related to some dependencies issue or mismatch version number, but I checked min and didn't find any mismatch: Reason: Java exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure

Comment: You told me in our chat that you use LTW in an OSGi setup I do not know more about, e.g. how you trigger weaving. Anyway, you need to put _aspectjweaver.jar_ on the classpath in order for AspectJ to find the runtime classes and be able to instrument your code. But that problem is way outside the scope of your original question here, which I already gave the correct answer to. So please accept the answer, if you agree.

Comment: right - thanks Alex, you're a real aspectJ professional guide :) !!! 1 up for you

Comment: I want to thanks @kriegaex for helping - the aspects are working, the issue with Reason: Java exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure  was because of equinox jars ordering initializing with other OSGI bundles. you learned me lot about aspects - thanks again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to solve your stated problem, but I would suggest a refactoring anyway.

You are effectively doing the same thing for 3 different annotations, so I would combine the different branches into one with a dispatcher, and I would probably go with an `@Around` advice, as suggested by @kriegaex.

The only thing I would change to his answer is to extract the identical bodies of the two `@Around` advices to a common method.

Comment: I used these ways and I got the below error and it doesn't so much clear what's the problem, I tried search on google and I found it could be related to some dependencies issue or mismatch version number, but I checked min and didn't find any mismatch: Reason: Java exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure

Comment: @ShicoRen sounds to me like you have an incompatible version of aspectjrt.jar on the classpath

Comment: Thanks @Sean Patrick Floyd the issue with Reason: Java exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure  was because of equinox jars ordering initializing with other OSGI bundles. you learned me lot about aspects - thanks again !!!

Comment: @ShicoRen always glad to help :-)